# Регулярные выражения и кириллица java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, почему регулярные выражения в Java не дружат с кириллицей?

```
public class New {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        String s = "5. Так как цель применения такого текста исключительно демонстрационная, то и  \n" +
                   "7. Более того, нечитабельность текста";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("искл\\w+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if(m.find())
            System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

В данном случае мы должны найти слово

> исключительно

но увы( А вот если мы изменим нашу строку s на:

```
"5. Так как цель применения такого текста exceptionally демонстрационная, то и  \n" +
"7. Более того, нечитабельность текста";
```

и заменим строку кода с регулярным выражением на:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("excep\\w+");
```

то получим

> exceptionally

без проблем. Как устранить проблему? Спасибо

Comment: @MaxZS, неправильно. Внутри Java все символы по 2-байта и в кодировке UTF-16 (правда некоторые символу Unicode кодируются парой символов (насколько помню их называют *суррогатная пара*)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Лучше так:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("иск\\w+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

Comment: Помоглось, спасибо!

Comment: а как быть если в паттерне есть несколько групп и одна группа должна искать в англ тексте, а вторая в русском? (пробовал парсить словарь англо-русский)

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) `\w` соответствует `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`. Попробуйте искать до ближайшего разделителя. Например так:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("искл[^\\u0000-\\u002f\\u003a-\\u003f]+");
```